# evaluating an option with a boolean in scala

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala, and I'm writing some code on top of existing JPA code in Java I can't modify (so rewriting the object isn't a solution here). Some of the values in the database are null, so unsurprisingly, when I try to do something like

```
if (myObject.nullAttributeTypeInt > someInt) {...}
```

I get a null pointer error. If I try something like this:

```
if(Option(myObject.nullAttributeTypeInt).getOrElse(1) > someInt) {...}
```

I get a compiling error, because the antecedent of the conditional is type Any, and the boolean operators aren't defined on it.

I assume there's some clever/concise way to deal with this using Option, but I can't find a ready answer. I could do something like

```
Option(myObject.nullAttributeTypeInt).getOrElse(1).toString.toInt
```

But that feels hacky. Thoughts? And thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution depends on what happens when the value is `null`.

If `null` is an automatic fail, you can do this:

```
if (Option(myObject.nullAttributeTypeInt).exists(_ > someInt)) { ... }
```

If it is an automatic success, you can do this:

```
if (Option(myObject.nullAttributeTypeInt).forall(_ > someInt)) { ... }
```

It you want `null` to give a default value, you can do this:

```
if (Option(myObject.nullAttributeTypeInt).fold(1)(_.toInt) > someInt) { ...}
```

Comment: Perfect; this was exactly what I was looking for. FWIW, option 1 was what I was looking for; the default value solution was only there to fit the Option-GetOrElse pattern I knew about. Thanks for answering the question I had in addition to the one I asked =).

Answer (score 2):

If the condition fails because the type of `myObject.nullAttributeTypeInt` is `java.lang.Integer` then you have to convert it to Scala's `Int` explicitly or implicitly.

You can use `Int.unbox` to unwrap Java's `Integer`:

```
Option(myObject.nullAttributeTypeInt).fold(1)(Int.unbox)
```

Or Scala can also unbox automatically if it knows the result must be Scala's `Int`:

```
Option(myObject.nullAttributeTypeInt).fold(1)(i => i: Int)
```

Alternative syntax with `match`:

```
Option(myObject.nullAttributeTypeInt) match {
  case Some(javaInt) => javaInt: Int
  case None => 1
}
```